# Template class two overload functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I created a template class of object and I want the second function to run if T==int. but My problem is that in the sec func() I want to run the first func on the Object.

How can I do this?

```
 template<typename T> Object<T>::func(){

 } 

 template<> Object<int> Object<int>::func(){
        //somecode
        // I want here run the first func() on the object.
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have another function `func_implementation` and forward to that.

Comment: Their is no way to do it by casting or something? super?

Comment: @Alon, no, there is no base class/derived class relationship between `Object<T>` and `Object<int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple matter of separating the interface from the implementation:

```
template<typename T> Object<T>::func_impl(){
  // Do stuff here
}

template<typename T> Object<T>::func(){
  // all func does is call func_impl
  func_impl<T>();
} 

template<> Object<int> Object<int>::func(){
  // Maybe do some stuff...
  func_impl<int>(); // ... then call your implementation...
  // .. and maybe do some more stuff
}
```

To clarify: what you're doing is **not** overloading. It's called **template specialization**. It's not possible to instantiate a generic template for a given type, if you provided a specialization for that type.

Comment: Ehm. What `T` in the last call to `func_impl<T>`?

Comment: @DanielJour Thanks for noticing. Corrected.